# How to get email from VK via oAuth library

Tags: php, vk

Anybody knows a way to get email id from vk social site? When I am trying, it is providing only below information.

```
stdClass Object (    [response] => Array (    [0] => stdClass Object    ( [uid] => 322372142     [first_name] => Gaurav    [last_name] => Pal     ) ) )
```

Am using above below code to make a call.

```
$success = $client->CallAPI('https://api.vk.com/method/users.get','GET', array(), array('FailOnAccessError'=>true), $user);
```

Comment: Have you tried to request [`email` permission](https://vk.com/dev/permissions)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found a way to get email from VK.

First fetch "CODE" from below url

```
https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&scope=email&redirect_uri=MY_REDIRECT_URL&response_type=code
```

Now send CURL request to get "EMAIL", "USER_ID", "ACCESS_TOKEN" from below url:

```
https://api.vk.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&client_secret=MY_CLIENT_SECRET_KEY&code=FETCHED_CODE&redirect_uri=MY_REDIRECT_URL
```

To get information other than email, use below URL

```
https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?uids=FETCED_USER_ID&access_token=FETCHED_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Answer (score -3):

There is no way to get user email or mobile phone attached to his page. You should not try. Just trust me as worker with vk api for many years.

Comment: Thank you to reply on my question.

I have seen other applications which are getting email id too from VK. When I login with my code, it is asking to authorize for sharing email id but in response, it is not giving email id :( 

Most probably I am using wrong scope while making call, but I have tried all scope which are mentioned on their site but still no luck.

Could you please check it once, may be they have made some update in their API.

Comment: what you mean by "email id"? "id" is identification number of page in social network vk.com, what email is we all know.

Comment: Sorry for causing misunderstanding. I was referring to email. There are apps which gets email too from VK API. When I login with those apps, they create my account with my VK email.

Comment: share an example of such app with me, I'll try to understrand how it do

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to help me with this issue.

I have found a way to get the email. I have added solution below.